# MySQL Function to return table name to be used in a query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, function, defined

Can I use a MySQL function or procedure to return table names that can be used in a query?

Something like

`SELECT * FROM get_db_table_name(2342352412);`

where `get_db_table_name()` is a user defined function which accepts a `user_id` as a parameter and returns the db.table where that user resides. I have not been able to do this this way because MySQL complains about the syntax (my guess is it's because I had to define a return type for the function, which I tried as `VARCHAR(30)` and it is wrong or impossible). So, is this possible?

The story is that I have a few databases that are essentially shards. Let's call them `user_1`, `user_2`, etc.

I also have a single table, say `emails` that contains records with `user_id`s from tables `user_1.users`, `user_2.users`, etc.

Since I know a way to compute which table an id is from just by looking at the id, I just want a function that would accept an input and return a db.table name to be used.

Thank you!

P.S. I'd like to use the above SELECT query as a VIEW definition that would bring the user's name from the proper db/table by doing a JOIN across the proper table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) for this, e.g.:

```
....
SET @tbl = 'nameofmytable';
SET @sql = CONCAT( 'SELECT * FROM ', @tbl );
EXECUTE @sql;
...
```

Comment: I don't think this would work in a VIEW declaration (see the P.S. in the main post). Can you provide a VIEW definition where this would work?

Comment: I'd say concatenating CREATE VIEW to @sql is not a problem either.

Answer (score 0):

When defining a view **you must specify the tables**. You can not define a view on "SELECT FROM whereever needed" ...

> The view definition is **“frozen”** at creation time, so changes to the underlying tables afterward do not affect the view definition. For example, if a view is defined as SELECT * on a table, new columns added to the table later do not become part of the view.

You must specify my view is on this, this and this table. Looking at this you can not do SELECT * FROM func(id) because you can not specify what the results of this function will be (depending on the input parameter).

The syntax of SELECT is

> SELECT * FROM table_references

The only way of "dynamic" SELECT is with dynamic SQL, what @Zed answered...

I'm sorry if my answer is incomplete, but I don't know your problem in details. Good Luck!

Comment: Well, the idea is to show the proper user's name, which means the VIEW has to know which table to look at. So far my best solution involves as many LEFT JOINs as I have user tables (dev env only has 2, so it kind of works out) and then a big if statement which puts the name from the appropriate table. I'd like to do it more elegantly though.

Answer (score 0):

Parameterising the table name is [considered to be usually because of bad database design](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_table). Is it really not possible to have all the entities of the same type (in this case, your users) in one table?